# PDF text mining using Python

Tags: python-3.x, ocr

I have Multiple PDFs having multiple pages. I want to extract only the required information out of the entire text. I have managed to read through the text and get it in a list, but unable to find the way to extract the required strings.Below is the code i could write :-

```
import PyPDF2
import io
import re
import pandas as pd

from pdfminer.converter import TextConverter
from pdfminer.pdfinterp import PDFPageInterpreter
from pdfminer.pdfinterp import PDFResourceManager
from pdfminer.pdfpage import PDFPage
mypdf = open('C:/XXXX/XXXXX/Desktop/7-29-19 Office Availabilities 1.pdf', mode='rb')
pdf_document = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(mypdf)

entry=[]
for page in PDFPage.get_pages(mypdf, 
                              caching=True,
                              check_extractable=True):
    resource_manager = PDFResourceManager()
    fake_file_handle = io.StringIO()
    converter = TextConverter(resource_manager, fake_file_handle)
    page_interpreter = PDFPageInterpreter(resource_manager, converter)
    page_interpreter.process_page(page)
    text = fake_file_handle.getvalue()

    entry.append(text)
     # close open handles
    converter.close()
    fake_file_handle.close()


Flyer= [x.split() for x in entry if x.startswith('FL')]
print(Flyer)
```

Below is the output i could get so far :-

```
["FloorSF AvailRent/SF/YrOccupancyTermBld OutLeasing CompanyUse/TypeContactListedDivisible1) 104-112 E 1st St - Sanford, FL 32771Rand Complex-40,000 SF Class C Office Building  Renovated in 1988 Built in 1910Hotard RealtyMarie Hotard (407) 467-5397Building Notes:-7,0001 yr2ndVacantOffice/N$7.80/mgN15 MthsMarie Hotard (407) 467-5397PHotard RealtyCall to negotiate renovation needs. Located in the heart of downtown Sanford's historic district, over 5,000 square feet ofoffice space on the second floor above bustling First Street. Historical building with great potential.2) 110 W 1st St - Sanford, FL 32771The Welaka Building-25,797 SF Class B Loft/Creative Space Building  Renovated in 1997 Built in 1887Brenner Real Estate E.Charles E. Brenner (407) 677-1700Building Notes:-366Negotiable2nd / Suite 214VacantOffice/D$22.00/fsN4 WksCharles E. Brenner (407) 677-1700PBrenner Real Estate198Negotiable2nd / Suite 234VacantOffice/D$22.00/fsN4 WksCharles E. Brenner (407) 677-1700PBrenner Real Estate1,276Negotiable2nd / Suite 240VacantOffice/D$16.00/fsN4 WksCharles E. Brenner (407) 677-1700PBrenner Real Estate743Negotiable2nd / Suite 242VacantOffice/D$18.00/fsN4 WksCharles E. Brenner (407) 677-1700PBrenner Real Estate1,357Negotiable2nd / Suite 246VacantOffice/D$16.00/fsN4 WksCharles E. Brenner (407) 677-1700PBrenner Real Estate720Negotiable2nd / Suite 250VacantOffice/D$18.00/fsN4 WksCharles E. Brenner (407) 677-1700PBrenner Real EstateCopyrighted report licensed to CBRE - 759852.7/29/2019Page 1\x0c",
 'FloorSF AvailRent/SF/YrOccupancyTermBld OutLeasing CompanyUse/TypeContactListedDivisible3) 734 N 3rd St - Leesburg, FL 347483rd Street Office Park-21,472 SF Class B Office Building  Built in 1974Grizzard Commercial Real EstateGroup, LLCDan Tatro (352) 396-9136Building Notes:City of Leesburg services and utilities including high speed DSL, fiber optic internet and phone systems all pre-wired and marked from central control room.ADA bathrooms & private executive and managerial offices.Security and central fire alarm system installed.1,564Negotiable1st / Suite Space 1VacantOffice/D$14.00/mgN29 MthsDan Tatro (352) 396-9136PGrizzard Commercial Real EstateGroup, LLC4) 900 N 14th St - Leesburg, FL 34748Trophy Leesburg Offices-40,302 SF Class B Office Building  Built in 1981Grizzard Commercial Real EstateGroup, LLCDan Tatro (352) 396-9136Building Notes:Building has 24 hour access.Join GSA and the Social Security Administration in this great Leesburg Office.  Current layout is perfect for high density office user.  Small modifications can bemade to accommodate anything from a small college to a large medical tenant.Great Central Florida location along busy US 27 and not far from The Villages.5,150Negotiable2ndVacantPartial Build-OutOffice/D$14.00/fsN10 MthsDan Tatro (352) 396-9136PGrizzard Commercial Real EstateGroup, LLC2nd Floor maybe divided into smaller units11,248Negotiable3rdVacantPartial Build-OutOffice/D$14.00/fsN10 MthsDan Tatro (352) 396-9136PGrizzard Commercial Real EstateGroup, LLC3rd Floor has 3 units that maybe divided or combined.Copyrighted report licensed to CBRE - 759852.7/29/2019Page 2\x0c',
```

The desired output is :-

```
['Flyer Number',    'Address',  'Total SF', 'Class',    'Suite/Bldg',   'SF available', 'Rent/SF/Year', 'Term', 'Occupancy',    'User/Type',    'Leasing company',  'Contact',  'Listed',   'Divisible',
'FL 32771', '104-112 E 1st St - Sanford',   '40,000 SF',    'C',    'P 2nd',    '7000', '$7.80/mg', '1 yr', 'Vacant',   'Office/N', 'Hotard Realty',    'Marie Hotard (407) 467-5397',  '15 Mths',  'N',
'FL 32771', '110 W 1st St - Sanford',   '25,797 SF',    'B',    'P 2nd/Suite 214',  '366',  '$22.00/fs ',   'Negotiable',   ' Vacant ', 'Office/D ',    'Brenner Real Estate',  'Charles E. Brenner (407) 677', '4 Wks',    ' N',
'FL 32771', '110 W 1st St - Sanford',   '25,797 SF',    'B',    'P 2nd / Suite 234 ',   '198',  '$22.00/fs',    'Negotiable',   ' Vacant ', 'Office/D ',    'Brenner Real Estate',  'Charles E. Brenner (407) 677', '4 Wks',    ' N',
'FL 32771', '110 W 1st St - Sanford',   '25,797 SF',    'B',    'P 2nd / Suite 240',    '1276', '$16.00/fs',    'Negotiable',   ' Vacant ', 'Office/D ',    'Brenner Real Estate',  'Charles E. Brenner (407) 677', '4 Wks',    ' N',
'FL 32771', '110 W 1st St - Sanford',   '25,797 SF',    'B',    'P 2nd / Suite 242',    '743',  '$18.00/fs',    'Negotiable',   ' Vacant ', 'Office/D ',    'Brenner Real Estate',  'Charles E. Brenner (407) 677', '4 Wks',    ' N',
'FL 32771', '110 W 1st St - Sanford',   '25,797 SF',    'B',    'P 2nd / Suite 246',    '1357', '$16.00/fs',    'Negotiable',   ' Vacant ', 'Office/D ',    'Brenner Real Estate',  'Charles E. Brenner (407) 677', '4 Wks',    ' N',
'FL 32771', '110 W 1st St - Sanford',   '25,797 SF',    'B',    'P 2nd / Suite 250',    '720',  '$18.00/fs',    'Negotiable',   ' Vacant ', 'Office/D ',    'Brenner Real Estate',  'Charles E. Brenner (407) 677', '4 Wks',    ' N']
```

Please help !!

Answer (score 0):

```
list = ["FloorSF AvailRent/SF/YrOccupancyTermBld OutLeasing CompanyUse/TypeContactListedDivisible1) 104-112 E 1st St - Sanford, FL 32771Rand Complex-40,000 SF Class C Office Building  Renovated in 1988 Built in 1910Hotard RealtyMarie Hotard (407) 467-5397Building Notes:-7,0001 yr2ndVacantOffice/N$7.80/mgN15 MthsMarie Hotard (407) 467-5397PHotard RealtyCall to negotiate renovation needs. Located in the heart of downtown Sanford's historic district, over 5,000 square feet ofoffice space on the second floor above bustling First Street. Historical building with great potential.2) 110 W 1st St - Sanford, FL 32771The Welaka Building-25,797 SF Class B Loft/Creative Space Building  Renovated in 1997 Built in 1887Brenner Real Estate E.Charles E. Brenner (407) 677-1700Building Notes:-366Negotiable2nd / Suite 214VacantOffice/D$22.00/fsN4 WksCharles E. Brenner (407) 677-1700PBrenner Real Estate198Negotiable2nd / Suite 234VacantOffice/D$22.00/fsN4 WksCharles E. Brenner (407) 677-1700PBrenner Real Estate1,276Negotiable2nd / Suite 240VacantOffice/D$16.00/fsN4 WksCharles E. Brenner (407) 677-1700PBrenner Real Estate743Negotiable2nd / Suite 242VacantOffice/D$18.00/fsN4 WksCharles E. Brenner (407) 677-1700PBrenner Real Estate1,357Negotiable2nd / Suite 246VacantOffice/D$16.00/fsN4 WksCharles E. Brenner (407) 677-1700PBrenner Real Estate720Negotiable2nd / Suite 250VacantOffice/D$18.00/fsN4 WksCharles E. Brenner (407) 677-1700PBrenner Real EstateCopyrighted report licensed to CBRE - 759852.7/29/2019Page 1\x0c",
'FloorSF AvailRent/SF/YrOccupancyTermBld OutLeasing CompanyUse/TypeContactListedDivisible3) 734 N 3rd St - Leesburg, FL 347483rd Street Office Park-21,472 SF Class B Office Building  Built in 1974Grizzard Commercial Real EstateGroup, LLCDan Tatro (352) 396-9136Building Notes:City of Leesburg services and utilities including high speed DSL, fiber optic internet and phone systems all pre-wired and marked from central control room.ADA bathrooms & private executive and managerial offices.Security and central fire alarm system installed.1,564Negotiable1st / Suite Space 1VacantOffice/D$14.00/mgN29 MthsDan Tatro (352) 396-9136PGrizzard Commercial Real EstateGroup, LLC4) 900 N 14th St - Leesburg, FL 34748Trophy Leesburg Offices-40,302 SF Class B Office Building  Built in 1981Grizzard Commercial Real EstateGroup, LLCDan Tatro (352) 396-9136Building Notes:Building has 24 hour access.Join GSA and the Social Security Administration in this great Leesburg Office.  Current layout is perfect for high density office user.  Small modifications can bemade to accommodate anything from a small college to a large medical tenant.Great Central Florida location along busy US 27 and not far from The Villages.5,150Negotiable2ndVacantPartial Build-OutOffice/D$14.00/fsN10 MthsDan Tatro (352) 396-9136PGrizzard Commercial Real EstateGroup, LLC2nd Floor maybe divided into smaller units11,248Negotiable3rdVacantPartial Build-OutOffice/D$14.00/fsN10 MthsDan Tatro (352) 396-9136PGrizzard Commercial Real EstateGroup, LLC3rd Floor has 3 units that maybe divided or combined.Copyrighted report licensed to CBRE - 759852.7/29/2019Page 2\x0c']
Requirements = ['Flyer Number',    'Address',  'Total SF', 'Class',    'Suite/Bldg',   'SF available', 'Rent/SF/Year', 'Term', 'Occupancy',    'User/Type',    'Leasing company',  'Contact',  'Listed',   'Divisible']
OutputList = []
for item in list:
    FlyerNumber = "FL" + (item.split("FL",1)[1])[:6]
    Address = (item.split(") ",1)[1]).split(",",1)[0]
    Squarefeet = str((item.split("SF Class",1)[0]).rsplit("-",1)[1]) + "SF"
    Class = (item.split("Class ",1)[1])[0]
    CollectedData = [FlyerNumber,Address,Squarefeet,Class]
    OutputList.extend(CollectedData)
print(OutputList)
FinalList = Requirements + OutputList
print(FinalList)
```

Printing `OutputList` will give you:

```
['FL 32771', '104-112 E 1st St - Sanford', '40,000 SF', 'C', 'FL 34748', '734 N 3rd St - Leesburg', '21,472 SF', 'B']
```

Printing `FinalList` will give you:

```
['Flyer Number', 'Address', 'Total SF', 'Class', 'Suite/Bldg', 'SF available', 'Rent/SF/Year', 'Term', 'Occupancy', 'User/Type', 'Leasing company', 'Contact', 'Listed', 'Divisible', 'FL 32771', '104-112 E 1st St - Sanford', '40,000 SF', 'C', 'FL 34748', '734 N 3rd St - Leesburg', '21,472 SF', 'B']
```

I found myself taking a long time going through every requirement needed. So here is half of them, from `Flyer Number` up to `Class`. Do make sure your information do not vary or else, the output might change.

**Code that is having issues:**

```
import PyPDF2
import io
import re
import pandas as pd

from pdfminer.converter import TextConverter
from pdfminer.pdfinterp import PDFPageInterpreter
from pdfminer.pdfinterp import PDFResourceManager
from pdfminer.pdfpage import PDFPage
mypdf = open('C:/Users/renu.sharma/Desktop/7-29-19 Office Availabilities 1.pdf', mode='rb')
pdf_document = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(mypdf)

entry=[]
for page in PDFPage.get_pages(mypdf,  
                              caching=True, 
                              check_extractable=True):
    resource_manager = PDFResourceManager()
    fake_file_handle = io.StringIO() 
    converter = TextConverter(resource_manager, fake_file_handle)
    page_interpreter = PDFPageInterpreter(resource_manager, converter) 
    page_interpreter.process_page(page)
    text = fake_file_handle.getvalue() 

    entry.append(text) 
     # close open handles
    converter.close()
    fake_file_handle.close()

Requirements = ['Flyer Number',    'Address',  'Total SF', 'Class',    'Suite/Bldg',   'SF available', 'Rent/SF/Year', 'Term', 'Occupancy',    'User/Type',    'Leasing company',  'Contact',  'Listed',   'Divisible']
OutputList = []
for item in entry:
    FlyerNumber = item.split("FL",1)[1])[:6]
    Address = (item.split(") ",1)[1]).split(",",1)[0]
    Squarefeet = str((item.split("SF Class",1)[0]).rsplit("-",1)[1]) + "SF"
    Class = (item.split("Class ",1)[1])[0]
    CollectedData = [FlyerNumber,Address,Squarefeet,Class]
    OutputList.extend(CollectedData)
FinalList = Requirements + OutputList 

print(OutputList)
```

Comment: Since you know the concept now, I think you can complete the rest.

Comment: :- Thanks for your response, but it is giving the following error 
          
         ---> 31     FlyerNumber = "FL" + (item.split("FL",1)[1])[:5]
                32     Address = (item.split(") ",1)[1]).split(",",1)[0]
                33     Squarefeet = str((item.split("SF Class",1)[0]).rsplit("-",1)[1]) + "SF"

IndexError: list index out of range
Please suggest

Comment: Which list are you using? By using the output that you said you were able to get. I'm getting no problems even from the error lines you gave. I think, it's from your input list. I'm just using the two element list that you provided from your question and it works fine..

Comment: I am using the exact code you suggested, but it gives error of index out of range for the "FlyerNumber" and "Class" lines

Comment: Hey @renu, because my code is working with the following list. I assume the error occurs because your list has a different pattern. Share with me the full list that you're using or at least part of it so I could spot the difference.

Comment: I think if you try understand my code, you will be able to fix the errors and complete the rest without a problem.

Comment: And the error is there only for two lines "FlyerNumber" and "Class" and NOT for "Address" and "SquareFeet"

Comment: And I'm using your list as well. Can you add your code to the top? For me to debug.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202309/discussion-between-hj-sin-and-renu).